# Resolve async method to a value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, methods, async-await

My aim is to make an object which has a number of Shared Access Signatures (SAS) for an Azure Storage Table. A sort of 'key vault' which holds a number of Signatures that I can use at will.

So I made an Azure Function that replies with the SAS when called.

And this javascript function uses an Ajax call to that Azure Function, like so:

```
    function fnGetTableSas(Table) {
            let strURL = SAS_GENERIC_TABLE_URI + "?table=" + Table;
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                headers: {"x-functions-key": "supersecretkeyhere=="},
                url: strURL,
            })
                .done(function (data) {
                    return(data);
                })
                .fail(function (error) {
                    return(error);
                });
    }
```

And then I'm making the following object with these methods:

```
    var SAS = {

        pageTable: async function () {
            await (fnGetTableSas("staging"))
        },

        orgTable: async function () {
            await(fnGetTableSas("organizations"))
        },

        userTable: async function () {
            await(fnGetTableSas("users"))
        },

    };
```

However when I use `page = SAS.pageTable();` then page is a Promise and not an actual value, even after it is resolved.

I'm probably using the wrong pattern to get to an object which holds the values of the asynchronous method.

What is a better way of doing this?

Comment: Are you  missing a return before $.ajax?

Comment: I think you also need to await SAS.pageTable();

Comment: I see, that could work.
But the whole aim is to create a sort of 'treasure chest' with a number of resolved Shared Access Signatures that I can use at will. Each SAS is valid for 15 minutes, so I want to set up an setInterval and change them before they expire